# compare csv files with bash\awk\shell

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I write script that perform compare  between csv files.
but I still have problem
I need that always be

5 values - space - 5 values

the problem is that there is lines that contain only 4 values, so I need to add instead of the missing value space columum

input:

File1:

```
1,1,1,1
3,3,3,3,3
```

File2:

```
2,2,2,2
4,4,4,4,4
```

now results look like that:

```
1,1,1,1, ,2,2,2,2
3,3,3,3,3, ,4,4,4,4,4
```

I need results look like this:

```
1,1,1,1, , , 2,2,2,2,*space* 
3,3,3,3,3, ,4,4,4,4,4
```

this is my code:

```
#! /bin/bash

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Description: Joins the files vartically based on the file extensions.
#
# Usage      : ./joinfile directory1 directory2
#
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#---- Variables ---------------------------------------------------------------

resultfile="resultfile.csv"

#---- Main --------------------------------------------------------------------

# Checking if two arguments are provided, if not, display usage info, and exit.
if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]
then
   echo "Usage: $0 directory1 directory2"
   exit 1
fi

# Checking if any of the arguments provided is not a directory.
if [ ! -d "$1" -o ! -d "$2" ]
then
   if [ ! -d "$1" ]
   then
      echo "Error: $1 is not a valid directory"
   fi

   if [ ! -d "$2" ]
   then
      echo "Error: $2 is not a valid directory"
   fi

   exit 1
fi

# Removing the end slash from the arguments, if user had provided.
dir1=$(echo "$1" | sed 's/\/$//')
dir2=$(echo "$2" | sed 's/\/$//')

# Creating an array of files having ^ in their filenames.
filearr=( $(ls "$dir1"/*^* "$dir2"/*^*) )

# Getting filearr length.
filearrlen=${#filearr[@]}

# Creating an array of extensions.
for (( i=0; i<"$filearrlen"; i++ ))
do
   extarr+=(${filearr[i]##*^})
done

# Removing duplicates and the last extension from an extarr.
OLDIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
newextarr=($(for i in "${extarr[@]}"; do echo "$i" | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//'; done | sort -du))
IFS="$OLDIFS"

# Getting newextarr length.
newextarrlen=${#newextarr[@]}

# Removing the previous outfile, if exists.
if [ -e "$resultfile" ]
then
   rm "$resultfile"
fi

# Joning the files vertically based on the extensions.
for (( i=0; i<"$newextarrlen"; i++ ))
do
   ext="${newextarr[i]}"
    echo "Handling ==> $ext"
   # Getting files with similar extensions.
   joinfiles=($(for j in "${filearr[@]}"; do echo "$j" | grep "\^$ext"; done))

   # Getting joinfiles array length.
   joinfileslen=${#joinfiles[@]}

   # Making a list of files to be pasted.
   for (( k=0; k<"$joinfileslen"; k++))
   do
      pastefiles+="${joinfiles[k]} "
        dos2unix "${joinfiles[k]}" 2>/dev/null
        cat "${joinfiles[k]}" | grep "^[ \t]*([0-9]* [0-9]*)," | sed 's/^[ \t]*//g'  | sort -t, -       k1 | cut -d',' -f1- >.ext_${k}_tags.csv
   done

   # Executing paste command.
   echo "==> ${ext}" >> "$resultfile"

awk 'BEGIN{ FS = "," }
{
if(FNR == NR){ a[$1] = $0 } else{ b[$1] = $0 }

for(i in a) { 
if (i in b) 
{ c[i]=a[i]", ,"b[i]; if (a[i] == b[i] ) { c[i]="True,"c[i]; } else { c[i]="False,"c[i]; } 
} else { c[i]="False,"a[i]", ,"i",MISSING-MISSING-MISSING";}
}
for(i in b) { 
if (! i in a) { c[i]="False,"i",MISSING-MISSING-MISSING, ,"b[i]; }
}
}
END{
for (i in c){ print c[i]; }
}
' ".ext_0_tags.csv" ".ext_1_tags.csv"|sort -t, -k1 >> "$resultfile"

rm -f ".ext_0_tags.csv" ".ext_1_tags.csv"

done

#---- End ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please only post the relevant parts of your code to provide a minimal example.

Comment: @TomFenech, Ok, I thinks it more clear

Comment: You need to edit your question and remove all of the parts that are unrelated to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you can solve your problem:

```
awk -F, '{a[FNR]=a[FNR] sprintf("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s%s",$1,$2,$3,$4,($5==""?" ":$5),(NR==FNR?", ,":""))}
END{for(i=1;i<=FNR;++i)print a[i]}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

This joins your two files together using an array. The `%s` in the `sprintf` statement take either the value of the column, or a space if the fifth column is empty. The final `%s` is replaced by comma if the first file is being processed. Once all of the records have been processed, the elements of the array are printed.

A number of assumptions are made here: it is assumed that only the fifth column can be empty and that there are an equal number of records in both files.

Output:

```
1,1,1,1, , ,2,2,2,2,
3,3,3,3,3, ,4,4,4,4,4
```

Comment: Have you tried doing so? Can you edit your question as I have suggested above?

Comment: I thinks u can help me in another way

I have the results file:

   t,1,1,1,1, ,2,2,2,2
   t,3,3,3,3,3, , 4,4,4,4,4

first column is Fixed always

I need results like this:

    t,1,1,1,1, , ,2,2,2,2,*space*
    t,3,3,3,3,3, ,4,4,4,4,4

Answer (score 1):

Another awk

Set field separator and out field separator to `,`
If less than 5 fields set field 5 to space.
Set array to line.
If second file print saved line and line from second file.

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, 'NF<5{$5=" "}{a[NR]=$0}FNR!=NR{print a[FNR]," ",$0}' file file2

1,1,1,1, , ,2,2,2,2,
3,3,3,3,3, ,4,4,4,4,4
```

I have assumed there are only 4 and 5 fields on the lines as if there were less than 4 this would not fill all empty fields with spaces.
Also assumed only two files.

Comment: That's a much nicer way!